# Docker-compose пробросить внутренний url наружу

Tags: docker, docker-compose

бекенд (php) стучится по пути  container_name: some а фронт по 127.0.0.1 и это для меня некорректно. мне нужно чтобы бек тоже мог по 127.0.0.1 стукнуться как фронт (на самом деле нет, просто юрлы дожны быть одинаковы). это реально?

```
            app:
               container_name: some

            ports:
            - '8090:8080'
```

в бекенд url - http://some:8080

в js - http://localhost:8090

мне бы их привести к общему знаменателю

Answer (score 0):

```
app:
   container_name: some
   networks:
      bd_external:
        aliases:
          - 'some.local'
      default:

networks:
  bd_external:
    external: true
```

и в /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 some.local
```

по пути http://some.local будет доступно приложение